# Does Docker Engine version 18.XX.X for windows exist and if so how do I download it?

Tags: windows, docker

We need a version 18.XX.X of docker engine community edition for windows and it would save us significant time to not have to approve a new version number of docker. When we go to the docker download link https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/ we only see 17.XX.X versions and all other links for windows seem to only provide the latest releases (19.03.4).  How can I download one of the 18.XX.X versions for windows or does these even exist?

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Hi! Nice to have you on board of stack overflow. I have found place where you can find previous releases of docker: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/ . I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for.